I'm trying to pull names from a matrix in a way that is double priority without scripts
I have a matrix of names and 0's in G3:O42, each row in the matrix has anywhere from 1 to 9 names starting on the left going to the right. Any row that doesn't have 9 names will have 0's. Each row pulls from the same list of names except some rows have certain names that other rows do not.
In D2:D42 I have this formula copied down =IFERROR(INDEX(G3:O3,MATCH(0,COUNTIFS(D$2:D2,G3:O3),0)),"")
This will pull the first name from each row that wasn't already pulled until I run out of names.
The problem is it's currently skipping some rows because all the names were used up. I need it to give me the highest priority still but I can't have it skip any rows. If there's 9 names total then the first 9 cells in D3:D42 need to be filled in.
An example of what I mean; In G8:O8 I have Matt, Jaime, Courtney then 0's. With Matt being the highest priority so it chose Matt for D8, Courtney was used already but Jaime was not used yet, in G9:09 I have Names that were already used including Matt then 0's. Since those names were already used it gives me a blank spot in D9 then goes onto D10 which has Jaime as an option and fills in her name.
In that scenario I would want D8 to choose Jaime and D9 to choose Matt then fill in blanks the rest of the way down.
I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve scripting. I can't figure this one out. I also hope I didn't miss anything. Thanks!
Input Data (D3:O42)




D
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O




3
Josh V
Josh V
Jaime
Matt
Courtney
Bader
0
0
0
0


4
Brandy
Brandy
Bader
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


5
Courtney
Courtney
Jaime
Matt
Bader
Josh V
0
0
0
0


6
Bader
Bader
Brandy
0
0
0
0
0
0
0


7
Frank
Frank
Bader
Courtney
0
0
0
0
0
0


8
Matt
Matt
Jaime
Courtney
0
0
0
0
0
0


9

Brandy
Bader
Courtney
Matt
0
0
0
0
0


10
Jaime
Josh V
Jaime
Bader
0
0
0
0
0
0


...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...
...


42

#CALC!
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0




would Jaime be okay in D9? Or does it have to match in the row?  Something like =UNIQUE(TOCOL(IF(G3:O3=0,NA(),G3:O3),3,TRUE)) would get you the list giving priority to the first column then the second and so on.

I would need the name in the D column to exist in the matrix at the same row #

Now you are getting into trying to get a computer to reason.  I do not think Formula will be able to make that happen.

Is it me or are you looking for a way to just sort your list? Using an extra column you could get that. Let's say you are using column C; place this formula in cell C3: =IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(D:D)/(D:D<>""),ROWS($C$3:C3))),"")

That will put Jaime in D9 which she cannot be in. I'm trying a workaround to sort the first n rows (n=7 or total number of names) by putting the stores with the least amount of people at the top so I'm less likely to have spaces. The problem is the matrix is already sorted. Each row is a store and the person in the D column is covering that store for a missing manager. So if I have 7 managers off one day then I'm going to need to D3:D9 filled if possible. So my workaround would be to sort the first n rows then overlap with the rest of the matrix. Sorry this is hurting my brain to explain.

Ok but in the end, if each of those stores are equally important (as you can sort them by number of avaiable managers), why would it matter where Matt or Jaime go? No matter what either store 9 or store 10 remains uncovered. As long as all managers are assigned, what's the problem with blank cells? Asking because i'm trying to understand what the actual goal is.

The store on the 9 row is very far away from Jaime so it's not in the area she can travel. I have a master matrix that has all the stores with each assistant manager who can work at each store in priority from left to right. The matrix in the problem above is already sorted by needed coverage for that day, if a store manager is off then it gets sorted to the top. If I have 5 store managers off and 6 assistant managers then the 5 stores should be covered and the 6th can be double coverage. I hope I explained that well.

I created a workaround that helps a lot and should solve the problem except for some rare cases. I put in a formula that when copied across creates a mirror of the matrix and gives a number in place of the name by how rare it is in the matrix. I then did a sum and ranked the matrix above by that sum. Then I created another matrix depending on how many store managers were off vs how many assistants were working, it takes the lowest number of the two and thats how many lines are in the new matrix. Then I changed the formula to pull data from the new matrix unless blank then pull from old.
